# What Good-aligned wizarding factions are there?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, forgotten-realms, factions

I play a 10th level neutral good gnome wizard. The majority of my party (barbarian, arcane trickster, warlock, Ranger, and druid) are part of factions in game. I've been trying to find a group in the Forgotten Realms to join to learn from.

So far the only real groups I've found are the Arcane Brotherhood and the Red Wizards of Thay. The only issue is that both of these groups are evil aligned.

Are there any factions for wizards that aren't evil? I've heard about Silverymoon and Blackstaff, but I can't find any information associated with those groups.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the one of the best solutions would be to ask your DM about that. You can work with him to create a group of wizards that fits your needs.

Though you are playing in the particular setting of the Forgotten Realms, there is nothing that forbids the creation of another group. The minor drawback is that it is extra work for the DM.

Comment: Just to add to this, what is to prevent you from spending your downtime being a founding member of a new group?

Comment: I had never actually considered starting my own group. I'm still relatively new to D&D and I'm still trying to figure out all of my character's possibilities.

Comment: @Thinkawick Understood but this game is all about possibilities both published options and the ones you create with your group :)

Comment: @Slagmoth Founding a new group isn't such a great idea if what you want from the group is to *learn* from them.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I concede that point but nothing stops new wizards coming in from having resources you didn't have with which to begin, thus learning from them in the process of them learning from you, while tackling common concerns. Also, look at it as a start up and the larger group just hears about your efforts and absorbs you into their network.

Answer (score 8):

In the city of Mulmaster you can find [the Brotherhood of the Cloak](http://dndadventurersleague.org/mulmaster_cloaks_logsheet.pdf).

The Elemental Evil storyline (season 2 of 5th edition Adventurer's League) provided a mechanic for tracking ranks within this organization as well as a [logsheet](http://dndadventurersleague.org/mulmaster_cloaks_logsheet.pdf).

Also there is a group who historically has opposed the Red Wizards, known as the [Covenant](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/The_Covenant). I guess they are based in Waterdeep now.

Answer (score 7):

## Join the [Church of Mystra](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Church_of_Mystra)

Mystra is the Neutral Good goddess of magic. Nice, good wizards are always welcome there, and can rub elbows with the bards, rangers, paladins, and clerics in the church. We strive to bring the benefits of magic to the world at large.

We hate Cyric, who's always wanting to kill Mystra, and we fight with his cultists whenever we get a chance.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the reference to "Blackstaff" in the question is referring to the Waterdeep's *Force Grey* (and the Gray Hands feeding into it), which is run by The Blackstaff. *Blackstaff* is both the title given to the head wizard of Waterdeep, and the special staff she wields. Her job appears to be to handle threats to the city that aren't military, but are beyond the capabilities of the regular Town Guard, and she runs a "private security force" for this purpose. That's Force Grey. Sort of like a private SWAT team.

They aren't specifically good-aligned, or wizard-centered, but she's a Wizard herself, and runs Force Grey out of Blackstaff Tower, which doubles as a Wizard academy.

As far as answering the question goes, I'd second Roflo's comment on the question about the [Harpers](https://dnd.wizards.com/dungeons-and-dragons/story/faction/harpers). They are good-aligned, but prefer to operate covertly rather than overtly, and are all about the acquisition of knowledge. Basically, spies for Good.

Because of that there's only a very narrow band of folks who they are apt to recruit: Good-aligned characters of Int/Cha based classes, like Wizards and Bards. You're in their sweet spot, and its a really tiny sweet spot, so why not look there?

Comment: The Harpers were the first group I thought of, as well. I edited a link to them into your answer. Lots of my Adventurers League spellcasters were Harpers.